# How do I make faces and vertices invisible in viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

I started learning Blender recently, however once I got to a point in a tutorial, it showed faces and vertices being invisible (2nd image), my view doesn't show this, despite, as far as I'm aware, having the same settings as in the tutorial, how do I make these become invisible? I'm sure it's a fairly simple fix, but the tutorial I'm using didn't have any information on how to change this

[image]

[image]

Comment: They went to Object Mode.

Comment: I went to object mode and I still have the same issue

Comment: With H you can hide stuff and Alt+H brings it back - in object mode all is back by default

Comment: That fully hides the objects though, in the tutorial it wasn't hidden, the objects still had an outline, just faces and vertices weren't visible

Comment: Could it be 'Solid' mode with 'X-Ray' set to full transparency in the  _Viewport Shading Options_? (dropdown, far right of the viewport header bar)

Comment: Are the normals for the faces correct?

Answer (score 1):

In your first picture, we see a cup of tea in object mode. No big deal.
In the second one, we see a cup of tea in edit mode. With a subdivision modifier display. But with optimal display On.

My guess is, your tutorial shows you a mesh modeled with a subdivision modifier, and the authors has it set so that in edit mode, the subdivision modifier displays a preview of its effect (that's the default behavior), but has the `Optimal Display` option checked on so that it doesn't draw the created geometry's wires:

[image: demo gif]

Answer (score -1):

[image: See Overlays and face normals]

Are the normals for your faces correct?